# Got Invalid Content Type while implementing message 91 API?

Tags: android, sms-gateway, android-webservice

I am facing a issue where I got invalid content type when I am hitting Message 91 API

I have used AndroidFastNetworking library to implement APIs, it perfectly works in Postman, but facing an error 'Invalid Content Type'

```
private void sendMsg(String no, String msg) {
        //send msg API call
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("sender", "NAINIS");
            jsonObject.put("route", "4");
            jsonObject.put("country", "91");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject joSMS = new JSONObject();
            jsonArray.put(joSMS);
            jsonObject.put("sms", jsonArray);
            joSMS.put("message", msg);
            JSONArray jaNumber = new JSONArray();
            joSMS.put("to", jaNumber);
            jaNumber.put(no);

            Log.i("jsonObject", "" + jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        AndroidNetworking.post("https://api.msg91.com/api/v2/sendsms")
                .addHeaders("authkey", "27XXXXXXXXXXXXXa")
                .addHeaders("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addQueryParameter("country","91XXXXXXXX8")
                .addJSONObjectBody(jsonObject) // posting json
                .setTag("test")
                .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("response", "" + response);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                        Log.d("error", "" + error.getErrorBody());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Here I got error like

```
{"type":"error","message":"Invalid content type.Please send data in formdata,application\/xml,application\/json format","code":""}
```

Answer (score 0):

This link might help

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2099

I faced similar issue where okhttp client was sending content-type as "application/json" along with charset as "utf-8" and msg91 server was not able to handle this.

I created the payload from jsonstring bytes it worked.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please read [how to ask good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).